# insert data into laravel 5 blade from array

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm puzzled over this one..

I have an array of arrays that I'm passing into a blade from a controller
data looks like this

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => AAAA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => BBBB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => CCCC
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => DDDD
        )

)
```

The controller passes it by calling the view as such

```
return view('items.pivot', compact('sites'));
```

and I attempt to display it in the blade like

```
@foreach($sites as $site)
    @if($site != '' || $site != null)
        <th class="col1" >{{$site->name}}</th>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

However what I get is the correct number of columns, but with each looking like

```
<th class="col1" ></th>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it must be obvious.. but I can't see it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're treating it like an object, while it's an array that you fed into view.

So change your code from `$site->name` to `$site['name']`

Comment: <facepalm>... friday <sigh>

Comment: you can mark answer as solved, so others viewers will get acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

It is an array and you are treating it as an object. Replace `{{$site->name}}` with `{{$site['name']}}`

Comment: Depends on your mentality bro, this is what you thinks :)